# Looking for an idiom meaning "you haven't changed"

Tags: idioms, conversation, idioms-in-context

Is there any idiom that means "you have not changed" that you could use in a conversation when you catch up with an old friend?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes,  "You haven't changed (a bit)" is the idiom.

Comment: *You haven’t changed a bit!* or *You look exactly the same [as you did the last time I saw you]*

Answer (score 1):

In a situation when a person's character, especially if it is bad, will not change, even if they pretend that it will, you can say:
**a leopard can't/doesn't change its spots**.
But Im not sure its usage about a person who remind you a positive feeling is correct or not.

Comment: This phrase can imply the speaker thinks the person will not change, and any attempts to change will fail.  It could still potentially be something friendly, like referring to a new beard not changing the person underneath.  However, it more often has a negative context, and I would avoid using it with friends.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compliment their youthful appearance being unchanged, you could say "You haven't aged a day!"

Informally, you could say "You're the same as always." to say they haven't changed, though I think this phrase might be somewhat regional.

Just saying "You haven't changed at all.", or "You haven't changed a bit." works well in many situations and sounds completely natural.